# Один сокет между несколькими потоками

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, сокет, udp

Здравствуйте!

Не нашел толковых ответов на эту тему.

На данный момент для взаимодействия с "железякой" используются сокеты. Я создаю сокет(DatagramSocket) на одном мне нужном порту(можно выбирать и случайный), все дальнейшие операции должны производиться именно с этого порта. Таймаут выставлен в 1 секунду. Во все остальные части(другие потоки) я передаю именно этот созданный экземпляр сокета.

Взаимодействую с ними следующими образами:

1. Периодический опрос(раз в 4 секунды) - этого требует устройство иначе оно выходит из режима "захвата". Использую встроенный  механизм Android - Timer;
2. Когда нужно получить какие-то данные с устройства или передать на него я создаю Thread, с помощью него отправляю запрос и получаю ответ. После того как работа законченна, тред останавливается(не зацикливаю);
3. Поток который должен крутится постоянно и воспринимать только нужные пакеты данных, остальные игнорировать. Его запускаю и он просто должен крутится(В нем то и вся проблема, до этого обходился без него).

Проблема следующая: при введение пункта 3, приложение перестает работать, как-будто сокет постоянно занят. Пример кода(класс из вышеупомянутого пункта 3):

```
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Message
import com.controller.labaratory.controller.App
import com.controller.labaratory.controller.models.Container
import java.net.*

/**
 * Created by ivan on 03/08/17.
 */
class DataPacketThread(val handler: Handler,
                       val socket: DatagramSocket,
                       val addres: InetAddress):Thread() {


    override fun run() {
        super.run()
        while (!socket.isClosed){
            try{
                //socket.soTimeout=0
                var buffer:ByteArray = kotlin.ByteArray(1024)
                val packet = DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.size)

                socket?.receive(packet)

                val odin:Byte = -1

                if (!(buffer[0] == odin)){
                    if(packet.data[0].toInt() == 4){
                        val responseByteArray:ByteArray = byteArrayOf(1,33,
                                packet.data[2],packet.data[3])

                        val packetResponseAnswer = DatagramPacket(responseByteArray,
                                responseByteArray.size, addres, 1026)
                        socket?.send(packetResponseAnswer)

                        handler?.sendMessage(
                                Message.obtain(
                                        handler,
                                        App.UdpClientHandler.DATA_PACKET_RECEIVE,
                                        HandlerContainer(825, Container(
                                                packet.length,
                                                packet.data))))
                    }

                }
            } catch (e:SocketTimeoutException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e:SocketException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
    }

    fun end(){
        socket.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: поставьте небольшой слип в конце тела while

Comment: Спасибо, поставил. В принципе, помогло. Но видимо подводный камень в том, что в момент когда потоком(из пункта 3) занят сокет, другие не могут к нему обратится. То есть существует вероятность, "наслаивания"?Я верно понимаю?

Comment: правильно понимаете

Comment: Вам просто надо организовать всю вашу кухню либо в одном потоке, либо использовать single thread executor для запуска заданий последовательно. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Comment: В одном потоке попытался сделать. Возникло две трудности. 1. Задачи(запросы) друг друга перебивали. 2. Недостаточно быстро отвечает, там где нужна скорость. Я начал копать в сторно nio: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703286/nio-datagramsocket-%d0%b2-android-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог разделить прием и посылку пакетов по двум разным потокам(Thread).
Ключевой код:

```
...
socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
socket.setReusedAdress(true);
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("your ip", port))
...
```

Таким образом можно работать с одним и тем же сокет-портом из разных потоков, без блокировки.