# NIO DatagramSocket в Android. Не получаю ответа или 0

Tags: java, android, сокет

Здравствуйте!
Разбираясь с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701873/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) вопросом, пришел к тому, что мне нужны неблокирующие сокеты.

Испробовал различные примеры - не удалось ничего из них запустить. Получаю либо ничего, либо 0.

В соответствии с тем, что я хочу сделать из предыдущего вопроса у меня появилось два варианта:

- Организовать все на блокирующих сокетах(столкнулся с определенными
  проблемами: скорость отклика, периодически пропадают запросы, в
  будущем возможна работа с видеопотоком)
- Разобраться в неблокирующих сокетах

Чтобы не быть голословным создал репозиторий на гитхабе, где выложил все мои [попытки](https://github.com/IvanShalimov/NIOLearn).

Ключевой участок кода в  примере с nio(не работает):

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;

/**
 * Created by ivan on 07/08/17.
 */

public class CatchThread extends Thread {

    byte[] data;
    DatagramChannel channel;
    int port = 1025;
    String address = "10.22.13.198";

    Handler handeler;

    public void setHandeler(Handler handeler) {
        this.handeler = handeler;
    }

    public CatchThread(byte[] array/*, DatagramChannel channel*/) throws IOException {
        data = array;


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        try {
            this.channel = DatagramChannel.open();
            this.channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(1025));
            this.channel.configureBlocking(false);
/*            Selector selector = Selector.open();
            this.channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            this.channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
            this.channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);*/

            this.channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.22.13.198", 1025));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            handeler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handeler,0,"bug: "+e));
        }

        //Send

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length);
        buf.clear();
        buf.put(data);
        buf.flip();

        try {
            int bytesSent = channel.send(buf,
                    new InetSocketAddress("10.22.13.198", port));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            handeler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handeler,0,"3"));
        }

        buf.clear();
        handeler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handeler,0,"5"));

        ByteBuffer bufReceive = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);

        while (channel.isOpen()) {

            try {
                int result = channel.read(bufReceive);//receive();
                handeler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handeler,0,"result: "+result));
                bufReceive.flip();

                while ( bufReceive.hasRemaining()) {
                    handeler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handeler,0,"Result: "+bufReceive.get()));
                }

                bufReceive.clear();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        handeler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handeler,0,"2"));

        try {
            this.channel.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Задача стоит следующая, надо сделать одним из способов взаимодействие с устройством по сети:

1. Держать один поток в программе и в нем организовать очередь запросов. Постоянно крутить цикл в потоке, проверяя есть ли что послать и посылать. После посылок будет идти блок где мы считываем не пришло ли что либо.
2. Можно сделать один поток который будет постоянно вертеть цикл и в нем прослушивать, не пришло ли что, а в отдельных потоках посылать запросы.

На блокирующих сокетах не удалось написать ни одного рабочего примера в одном потоке, только раздельно. В итоге получалась конкуренцая за сокет.
На неблокирущих не удалось получить даже примитивного запрос/ответ( я выясняю в чем дело)

Comment: Добавляйте код прямо в вопрос, ссылки на внешние ресурсы могут служить только дополнением

Comment: Но в чем проблема реализовать свою обертку, которая будет в отдельном потоке принимать пакеты и добавлять их в очередь?`скорость отклика` - в чем проявляется? возможно вы блокируете gui поток. `периодически пропадают запросы` - в этом и заключается отличие tcp от udp - udp не гарантирует доставку пакетов, вы должны сами следить за доставкой критичных данных. `в будущем возможна работа с видеопотоком` - тут тоже не понял в чем проблема, возможно это опять таки связано с поведением udp. Если у вас возникают такие проблемы - может вам больше подойдет tcp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После всех попыток пришел к выводу что через java.nio связать в моем случае не получиться( просто не работает).
Смог разделить прием и посылку пакетов по двум разным потокам(Thread).
Ключевой код:

```
...
socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
socket.setReusedAdress(true);
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("your ip", port))
...
```

Таким образом можно работать с одним и тем же сокет-портом из разных потоков, без блокировки.